# How to run JavaScript codes after CSS background-image is loaded

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I want to run a JavaScript code (simple animation with addEventListener) after CSS background image is loaded.

I don't want to use JavaScript Image() for this case because there are two background-image for small size screen and large size screen each. If I use Image(), the image cannot be switched when changing the screen size after loaded.

The background image is loaded on body in CSS, not as img tag in a specific section in html because I want to cover header and hero section (which is in main tag) with it.

```
body {
    background: no-repeat url("../img/bg_sp.png");
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background: no-repeat url("../img/bg_pc.png");
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event `load` event. 

Comment: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/animation-duration/

Comment: It worked, thank you! I don't know why I overlooked this while I searched for the past few hours. This is exactly what I was looking for.